# access website localStorage from chrome extension popup open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to read the localStorage value of the open tab in the chrome extension when I open the popup.html

I already tried with chrome.storage.local and chrome.storage.sync but I am getting undefined

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
    console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

also tried chrome.tabs.executeScript as well and gives undefined only.

```
var fromPageLocalStore = chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: `localStorage['branch_session_first']` });
```

Can you please help me to get the active tab's localStorage value using the chrome extension?

Comment: executeScript is the correct approach but the value will be available in its callback, see the documentation and examples.

Comment: Never mind I have checked the document and got the solution for it. I can't get localstorage data from the chrome extension. I used sendMessage in content.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solution for this question by using sendMessage and onMessage Listener functions.

below is the code

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    info: localStorage['key'] //get from tab's local storage
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    localStorage['key'] = message.key; //store into extension's local storage
});
```